# Links with relative path in <iframe> doesn't work based on the loaded html file location

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, relative-path, html5-filesystem

Now I am running web app at `https://example.com`

And there, I am gonna open the html file from my "PC - local file system" and render its content in iframe.

But the file-content contains links with relative path such as `<script src="1.js"></script>` and it tried to find `https://example.com/1.js`

Is there any way to make it find the `1.js` based on my local file location?

So here's the example

```
My folder structure is like below

Directory1
   Html1.html
   Js1.js

And at "https://example.com", I open the "Html1.html" and render its content in <iframe> tag
The "Html1.html" has "<script src="Js1.js"></script>" in it.
Now it finds "https://example.com/Js1.js" instead of the local file.
```

So I tried to get the absolute path of the local file when opening it in the browser, but couldn't.